# Why is my map not in the center when I load my map in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, cartography, layers

Why is my map not in the center when I load my map in OpenLayers? And when I drag my map, it doesn't move sometimes.

```
var maxExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(103.30029292030527, 24.39151279999997, 109.88812867358875, 29.45420120000002);
        function init() {
            var jsonp = new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script();
            jsonp.createRequest(layerURL, {
                f: 'json',
                pretty: 'true'
            }, initMap);
        }

        function initMap(layerInfo){
            var baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache("AGSCache", layerURL, {
                isBaseLayer:true,
                layerInfo: layerInfo,
                StartBounds: maxExtent,
                transitionEffect:'resize'

            });
            /*
             * Make sure our baselayer and our map are synced up
             */
            console.log( baseLayer.maxExtent);
            map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
               // restrictedExtent: maxExtent,
                //startBounds: maxExtent,
               startBounds: maxExtent,
                maxExtent: baseLayer.maxExtent,
                units:"degrees",
                resolutions: baseLayer.resolutions,
                numZoomLevels: baseLayer.numZoomLevels,
                tileSize: baseLayer.tileSize,
                displayProjection: baseLayer.displayProjection
            });
            map.addLayers([baseLayer]);

            /*
            *  delete the default controls
            * */
            var zoomControl = map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.Zoom')[0];
            map.removeControl(zoomControl);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Attribution());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({dragPanOptions: {enableKinetic: true}}));
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar({zoomWorldIcon:true}));
          // map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LoadingPanel());
            if (!map.getCenter()) {
                map.zoomToMaxExtent();
            }
            /*zoom the map to a special level
             map.zoomTo(3,(107.4833233,26.23578279));
            map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(107.4833233, 26.23578279), 2);*/
             map.zoomTo(0);
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition() );
            //map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(-8341644, 4711236, -8339198, 4712459));
          //  map.zoomToExtent(new OpenLayers.Bounds(103.30029292030527, 24.39151279999997, 109.88812867358875, 29.45420120000002));
        }
```

Comment: you should remove map.zoomTo(0);.

Comment: Hi,neogeomat!Thanks for your reply,that's really work,but a little not so fine,do you konw why when I drag my map,it didnt move on sometimes?

Comment: was it at the boundaries, you have set the maxextent according to baselayer. were you outside your extent.

Comment: I set the extent strictly,but it seems that when I use consolg.log(map.maxextent);,the output result became larger than the extent I have set.This really confused me,hope your reply!Here is the console.log result:bottom: 24.3915128
left: 103.30029292031
right: 109.88812867359
top: 29.4542012

Comment: can you use without using the extent?